# How to say "self-isolation" or "quarantine" in japanese

Tags: translation, word-choice, word-requests, english-to-japanese

I want to ask "Do you eat more in self-isolation/quarantine?" and "Do you exercise less in self-isolation/quarantine?".
What is the simplest translation for these sentences and can I use something like「[japanese word for self-isolation/quarantine]の時、もっと食べますか?」for the first sentence?

Comment: You changed your question after I answered it.

Answer (score 1):

自主隔離{じしゅかくり} is one term for 'self-isolation' which has been used in Japanese media. For example, check this article [here](https://www.asahi.com/articles/ASN3G31Y0N3GUHBI006.html).

For 'quarantine', just 隔離{かくり} is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the term 自宅待機 during this Covid-19 crisis, which [according to Jisho.org](https://jisho.org/search/%E8%87%AA%E5%AE%85%E5%BE%85%E6%A9%9F), means:

> 1. standing by at home (e.g. to prevent the spread of illness)​
> 2. being on furlough; being temporarily laid off